# jQuery address – html() or AJAX request?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a problem. I'm trying to integrate jQuery address http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/ into my website. As a test, I've created a test website http://electricchapel.net/ecad/. It works, but I've got one question:

What is the difference between using `html();` and a jQuery AJAX load? I'm trying to build a website with this "plug-in" to decrease traffic in the future and to improve loading times. But there will also be self-refreshing and dynamical content in the jQuery address loaded `div`. If I should rather use AJAX, could you please help me to include the AJAX function? The jQuery address documentation is very poor and hard to understand for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No real difference. When calling .load() using a URL without a suffixed selector expression, the content is passed to .html() prior to scripts being removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If .load() is however called with a selector expression appended to the URL, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated, which is why they are never executed. An example of both cases can be seen here: http://api.jquery.com/load/